# Wordpress hook to authenticate user for pre-defined URLs

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a fairly complex project that has many frontend editing pages. For example, add/edit/list custom post types, edit profile, and so on, all from the frontend.

At the moment I can of course check if user is logged in on each frontend login-walled page. However, this seems like a bad way of solving this problem as I'll have the same conditional on many pages and thus lots of repeated code.

I was thinking perhaps there is a better way where I could authenticate based on some hook (that I can't finds). I hoped I could do something like:

```
# create array of URLs where login is required
$needLoginArr = array(url1, url2, url3, ...)

# If current requested URL is in above array, then redirect or show different view based on whether or not user is logged in
```

It might not be practical in future to have conditional on each page as I plan on integrating within different plugins, so would be useful to use URL to authenticate.

I'm probably missing something here so if there's a better way please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your list of page IDs into an option:

```
$need_login = array(
    'page1',
    'page1/subpage',
    'page2',
    // and so forth
);
$need_login_ids = array();
foreach( $need_login as $p ) {
    $pg = get_page_by_path( $p );
    $need_login_ids[] = $pg->ID;
}
update_option( 'xyz_need_login', $need_login_ids );
```

Then, to check if your page is in the `$need_login` group:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'so20221037_authenticate' );
function so20221037_authenticate( $content ) {
    global $post;
    $need_login_ids = get_option( 'xyz_need_login' );
    if( is_array( $need_login_ids ) && in_array( $post->ID, $need_login_ids ) ) {
        if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            // alter the content as needs
            $content = 'Stuff for logged-in users' . $content;
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

#### References

- [`get_page_by_path()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path)
- [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)
- [`update_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)
- [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, Pat. I think the issue with this solution in my case is that I am using various page templates that include the code I need to protect. Therefore everything outside of the content (but within the page template) will still be available.